# Is there way to change this mass assignment design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 models, User, Army and Engineer. When a User creates an Army which belongs to them, they can check a checkbox called `siege` that  will create an Engineer which belongs to that Army and User. I have a concern about mass assignment though. The Engineer gets created by my method in my Army model:

```
attr_reader :siege
after_save :if_siege
private
 def if_siege
   if self.siege
    Engineer.create!( :user_id => self.user.id, :army_id => self.id )
   end
 end
end
```

But the only way that I know of to have both of the ID's be assigned is to do this in my Engineer model:

```
class Engineer
 attr_accessible :user_id, :army_id
```

This doesn't seem safe even though engineers can never be created on a form but will automatically be created by a link or checkbox. The ideal is Auto-assign these two attributes like whats done in the controller. e.g.

`example = current_user.examples.build(params[:example])`

What do you think? Is their an alternative to this design?

Mass assignment is a tricky issue for me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
engineer = Engineer.new
engineer.user_id = self.user.id
engineer.army_id = self.id
engineer.save!
```

You could alternatively specify that you don't care about the mass assignment issues here only:

```
params = { :user_id => self.user.id, :army_id => self.id }
Engineer.create!(params, without_protection: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to relate the Engineer to the User explicitly? If you related the Engineer to the Army, wouldn't that Engineer get the relationship through Army to the User?